# Decades of unaccounted time for Gotrek and Felix

Tags: books, warhammer-fantasy, gotrek-felix

Is there any book / short story / article dedicated to the decades Gotrek and Felix spent in Ind and Araby between the events of Giantslayer and Orcslayer?

This is the only relevant quote from Orcslayer [I could find online](http://www.blacklibrary.com/Downloads/Product/PDF/o/orcslayer.pdf), but they mention they've been in Ind and Araby for decades once or twice in the early chapters of the book.

> 'War?’ asked Gotrek. ‘What war?’
>
> ‘You don’t know of the war?’ asked the harbourmaster. ‘Where have
>   you been?’
>
> ‘Ind and Araby,’ spat Gotrek, ‘chasing our tails.’
>
> ‘You say this war is in the Empire?’ asked Felix.

I've looked though the Black Library website and have not been able to find anything which covers this period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deep inside [Gotrek and Felix - The Anthology](https://sfbook.com/gotrek-and-felix-the-anthology.htm), is a short story called [Kineater](http://www.blacklibrary.com/all-products/kineater-ebook.html). It takes place between the events of Giantslayer and Orcslayer.

Kineater takes place in the Orge Kingdom, but Gotrk and Felix have travelled directly from Ind as mercenaries with an Arabyan caravan.

One of the characters is perusing Felix's journals and points out the following, most recent entry:

> Here, you have a giant six times the height of a man, despite the fact that any such creature would collapse under it's own weight

Obviously this is a reference to the giant in Giantslayer.

**UPDATE**

After reading the rest of Gotrek and Felix - The Anthology, which is a collection of short stories, it's pretty clear that most of them take place in Ind / Araby. While not really a comprehensive account of their time there, it's something.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Finally!

[The Serpent Queen](http://www.blacklibrary.com/Warhammer/gotrek-felix-the-serpent-queen.html), an entire full length novel that takes place between Giantslayer and Orcslayer.

I have not read it myself yet, but the review on [The Founding Fields](http://thefoundingfields.com/2014/09/gotrek-felix-the-serpent-queen-by-josh-reynolds-book-review-bellarius/) says the following:

> Set during the duo’s travels away from the Empire between Giantslayer and Orcslayer...

The Founding Fields is usually quite reliable. Success!